# Matlab FFT: Power Spectral Density or Amplitude Spectral Density?

Tags: matlab, fft, psd

The amplitude of a FFT should be depending on the length of the signal.
To display the result in a independent way the Power Spectral Density or the Amplitude Spectral Density should be used. There are calculated as follows:
Amplitude FFT = Y
Signal Length = L
Power Spectral Density PSD = Y^2/L
Amplitude Spectral Density ASD = Y/sqrt(L)
https://www.sjsu.edu/people/burford.furman/docs/me120/FFT_tutorial_NI.pdf

My problem is, that the result of the Matlab fft is already indipendent from the signal length and I do not understand if this is already a PSD or a ASD.

Let's take the Matlab example Noisy Signal: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html
If we make the FFT on the same signal, but twice or ten times longer, the FFT amplitude does not change.
This because of the line:
`P2 = abs(Y/L);`
where the amplitude is divided through the signal length. But why is the formula different from the PSD or the ASD formula and we still obtain amplitudes indipendent from the signal length?

In this example it is shown, that the two signals, ones for 50s, ones for 500s, has almost the same amplitudes.

```
    % Signal 1    
    sps = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
    T = 1/sps;                     % Sampling period
    Frequency1 = 150;              %  frequency 1 [Hz]
    SignalAmplitude1 = 1;          % mm/s
    Frequency2 = 45;               % dominant frequency [Hz]
    SignalAmplitude2 = 1.2;        % mm/s
    L = 50;                        % Length of signal, sek.
    L = L*1000;                    % convert to ms
    time = (0:L-1)*T;              % Time vector
    Signal = cos(2*pi*Frequency1*time)*SignalAmplitude1 + sin(2*pi*Frequency2*time)*SignalAmplitude2;

    f = sps*(0:(L/2))/L;
    FFTcomplex = fft(Signal);
    P2 = abs(FFTcomplex)/L;
    P1 = P2(:,round(1:L/2+1));
    P1(:,2:end-1) = 2*P1(:,2:end-1);
    Ampl_FFT_1 = P1;

    % Signal 2
    sps = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
    T = 1/sps;                     % Sampling period
    Frequency1 = 150;              %  frequency 1 [Hz]
    SignalAmplitude1 = 1;          % mm/s
    Frequency2 = 45;               % dominant frequency [Hz]
    SignalAmplitude2 = 1.2;        % mm/s
    L = 500;                        % Length of signal, sek.
    L = L*1000;                    % convert to ms
    time = (0:L-1)*T;              % Time vector
    Signal = cos(2*pi*Frequency1*time)*SignalAmplitude1 + sin(2*pi*Frequency2*time)*SignalAmplitude2;

    f = sps*(0:(L/2))/L;
    FFTcomplex = fft(Signal);
    P2 = abs(FFTcomplex)/L;
    P1 = P2(:,round(1:L/2+1));
    P1(:,2:end-1) = 2*P1(:,2:end-1);
    Ampl_FFT_2 = P1;

    sum(Ampl_FFT_2)-sum(Ampl_FFT_1)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. First of all, it seems to me that your question is not in the scope of programming but rather signal processing, so I would consider to ask it here : [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions). Also it is not one question but a few, I would focus only at one and progress from there. Why do you say that the result of the FFT is independent of the lenght of the signal?

Comment: Hi Irreducible and thanks for your time.  The result of the FFT, divided through the signal length, is independent of the length of the signal => the amplitudes in the vectors Ampl_FFT_1 and Ampl_FFT_2 are the same.  But my question is: Why divide through L instead of through sqrt(L) to obtain an indipendent amplitude? Dividing through  sqrt(L) should be the right way to obtain the Amplitude Spectral Density.
Is it ok if I post the question twice, onces here and ones in DSP.SE? Or should I have to close this question first?

Comment: So the result of the fft is dependent of the signal length, the post processing is what you are curios about. So why should the amplitude of a 5 seconds signal be larger than the one of a the same signal which was recorded for 3 seconds? yes you can also post the question there.

Comment: Ampl_FFT_1 and Ampl_FFT_2 are not different in your example because they are created separately, with their own L value. If you re-write your code to use L_1 and L_2 you will see what I mean.

Comment: @mhopeng: Changed the code, but the result remains the same...

Comment: @Irreducible: There is more energy in 5 seconds, for this reason the amplitude of the fft is greater for the 5 seconds signal compared to the fft amplitude of the 3 seconds signal.
The signal amplitude itself (not fft) is always the same.

Comment: So then everything is fine, the amplitude has to be the same, and the output of the fft has to be different. Where is the problem?